# Is there a way to snap face to the cursor without all its vertices collapsing to a point?

Tags: modeling, mesh, 3d-cursor

I am making a structural latticework, the kind of supports you see on the back of radio telescopes or radar dishes. It is a lot of small struts in triangular and square configurations.

It would be much easier if I could place the 3D cursor where a joint should be, and then make the end faces on the right struts all snap to the cursor.

But when I do that, they all collapse to a single point. It seems like if I do it right, I should be able to prevent that. It is in face select mode, pivot center in individual origin mode.

[image: screenshot of mesh snapped to a single point]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are very close.

The selection mode makes no difference.
All you have to do is press <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>S</kbd> > *Selection to Cursor **(Offset)***.

Or you could Press the *Offset* button in the tool options (that option is there whether you use *"Selection to Cursor"* or *"Selection to Cursor (Offset)"*).
[image: Selection to Cursor option]

Comment: Great. My faith is restored. :) I see i have to move one strut at a time or the end faces space themselves evenly around the cursor. I'm sure that will be very useful in other situations, right now it just multiplies the number of times i have to click. Sigh, so life is still not perfect...